# Exception handling and lifecycle on Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to learn and test exceptions in android and can't seem 
to get information past try/catch, Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler()) and ACRA.

Basically I want to know what happens when an Exception is thrown, does it kill only the current activity? What if my application has multiple activities and its killed in the 4th activity that is in the stack of activities, does it kill just the one?

I ask mainly because I am throwing an error and its not killing the complete program but restarting it at some middle activity of the program. (I am doing this on purpose to learn more about it) I would either prefer the program dies, than restart in some bad state, but
Android has no kill switch (at least that I know of).

Thanks

EDIT: If android recreates the stack, do we know how far it goes? or if it uses create? or resume? What if the previous activities in the stack needed user input?

Answer (score 2):

What I have observed from the LogCat is that android sort of caches the intents and tries to re-construct your stack from those. What I mean is, say you activity stack consists of Activity A, B, C, D (D on top, A at bottom) and an exception is thrown in Activity D. Then the OS tries to reconstruct the stack by firing intents for A, then B and then C. But I'm not sure about it

Comment: Since there's no application in the traditional desktop sense, this behavior (if it's correct) would be very logical.  If there's a set of nearly independent activities, the whole set doesn't need to die horribly when one activity blows up.  That would be akin to a single desktop application bringing down the whole system.

Comment: My problem is that in the process of recreating the stack its missing something along the way, and it recreates it wrongfully. (its not reloading the DB)

Comment: I'm sure that while recreating the activity the onCreate method is called. Is it possible that your activity creation is dependent on some data which was available earlier but is not present after the crash. What I mean is, earlier I used to store a data-structure as a static variable in a singleton class and used it to create my activity. After the crash I saw that sometimes data-structure was not available to my activity and it was rendered in-correctly

Answer (score 2):

My impression has been that the Android framework prints out a stack trace from the uncaught exception then restarts the VM with everything but the Activity that caused the exception.  For example, I had an uncaught Null Pointer exception in an activity and a background sticky service running.  Android attempted to restart the VM and restart the sticky service, but I incorrectly implemented the service to always look at the intent starting it which is NULL on restart causing a second exception immediately afterwards.

Also, at least in Eclair and above, Android will attempt to restart a service after certain crashes such as an uncaught exception in onStartCommand().  In that case, onStartCommand() will be called with the flag START_FLAG_RETRY.

Some insight into this is here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/0eb714f48d534443

Answer (score 2):

> Android has no kill switch

You might try System.exit(int), from Java SE, which kills the virtual machine.

> If android recreates the stack, do we know [...] if it uses create? or resume?

onCreate is called (see http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png)

BTW, an Exception does kill the program, but the ActivityManager restarts it.
If the previous Activities required user input on which the front Activity depends, it should be put into the Bundle which is put into the Intent which starts the front Activity, because the system saves the Bundle and passes it again to the Activity when restarting it.